# I can't understand why the third column (N) has different width from the rest

Tags: column-width

[image]
I tried using `\!` or `\hspace{-1em}`.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
%Checkout https://texblog.org/2014/05/19/coloring-multi-row-tables-in-latex/
% and https://www.baeldung.com/cs/latex-tables-vertical-horizontal
\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \caption[Comparison of all model predictions for of genetic circuit failures, and the most ``robust" circuit choice for each model simulation.]{Comparison of all model predictions for of genetic circuit failures, and the most ``robust" circuit choice for each model simulation. \textbf{D}: default parameter values; \textbf{C}: characterized parameter values; \textbf{O}: original design; \textbf{T}: two-inverter design; \textbf{N}: no-logic-hazard design (or logic-hazard free design).}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c?{2pt}c|c|c?{2pt}c|c|c|}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Default Model}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Cello Model}}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} \\
        \cmidrule(rl){3-5} \cmidrule(rl){6-8} \cmidrule(rl){9-11}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Circuit Failures}}&   O   &   T   & N &   O   &   T   &   N   &   O   &   T   &   N   \\
        \midrule
        & $(0,1,0) \rightarrow (1,1,1)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & \\ 
        & $(0,1,0) \rightarrow (1,0,0)$ & & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} \\
        & $(1,1,1) \rightarrow (1,0,0)$ & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & \\      
        & $(1,1,1) \rightarrow (0,1,0)$ & & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & & \\
        & $(1,0,0) \rightarrow (0,1,0)$ & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime}\\
        \multirow{-6}{*}{0-Function Hazards}& $(1,0,0) \rightarrow (1,1,1)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & &\cellcolor{red} & & & \cellcolor{red} & \\
        \specialrule{\cmidrulewidth}{3pt}{3pt}
        & $(0,1,1) \rightarrow (1,0,1)$ & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime}\\
        & $(0,0,0) \rightarrow (0,1,1)$ & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \\
        & $(0,0,0) \rightarrow (1,0,1)$ & & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red}\\
        & $(1,0,1) \rightarrow (0,1,1)$ & & & & & \cellcolor{red}& \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} &  \\      
        & $(0,1,1) \rightarrow (0,0,0)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red}  & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red}\\
        \multirow{-6}{*}{1-Function Hazards}& $(1,0,1) \rightarrow (0,0,0)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & & & \cellcolor{red}& \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & \\
        \specialrule{\cmidrulewidth}{3pt}{3pt}
        & $(0,0,0)$ & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red}\\
        & $(0,0,1)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime}\\
        & $(0,1,0)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} &\cellcolor{lime} \\
        & $(0,1,1)$ & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & \\     
        & $(1,0,0)$ & & & \cellcolor{lime} & & & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{lime} & & \\
        & $(1,0,1)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & & & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{red} & & \cellcolor{lime}\\
        & $(1,1,0)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & & & & \cellcolor{red} & \\
        \multirow{-8}{*}{Wrong Steady-State}& $(1,1,1)$ & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & & \cellcolor{red} & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{lime} & \cellcolor{red} & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \\[1.5pt]
    \centering
    \small This table compares each models' predictions for best and worst performance for each transition. A red color means that the circuit performed worse than the median, and green color means that the circuit performed better than the median, for that input molecule concentration or transition. 
    \label{tab:failuresALL}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The text in `\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Default Model}}` is too wide. You could load the `makecell` package and say: `\multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{\textbf{Default}\\ \textbf{Model}}}`.

Comment: Oh how dumb am I. You are a genius thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @JasperHabicht has already noted in a comment, the reason for the excessive width of column 5 is that the header of columns 3 thru 5 is "too wide", in the sense that the width of the string "Default Model" exceeds the combined natural widths of the three individual columns by far. The excess width of the header string has to be reflected somewhere in the actual widths of one or more of the underlying columns. What you've (re)discovered is that LaTeX allocates the excess width to the final column in the group of columns below the wide header.

A second issue is that the table is too wide overall and doesn't fit inside the text block. In the code below, I apply various changes to your code to make the table fit. One of them is to change the aforementioned header from "Default Model" to just "Default". I would also recommend getting rid of all vertical rules to give the table a more open "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\color{white}\vrule width #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp]
\newcommand\red{\cellcolor{red}} % handy shortcut macros
\newcommand\lime{\cellcolor{lime}}

\caption[Comparison of all model predictions of genetic circuit failures, and the most ``robust'' circuit choice for each model simulation.]{Comparison of all model predictions of genetic circuit failures, and the most ``robust'' circuit choice for each model simulation. }
\label{tab:failuresALL}

\medskip
\textbf{D}: default parameter values; \textbf{C}: characterized parameter values; \textbf{O}: original design; \textbf{T}: two-inverter design; \textbf{N}: no-logic-hazard design (or logic-hazard free design).
    
\smallskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cc ccc ?{3pt} ccc ?{3pt} ccc }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Circuit Failures} & 
\multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Models} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-11}
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Default} & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Cello}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule{6-11}
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} \cmidrule(r){6-8} \cmidrule{9-11}
& &  O & T & N &   O & T & N &   O & T & N \\
\midrule

0-Function Hazards
 & $(0,1,0){\to}(1,1,1)$ & & \red & & & \red & \lime & & \red & \\ 
 & $(0,1,0){\to}(1,0,0)$ & & & \lime & & \red & \lime & & & \lime \\
 & $(1,1,1){\to}(1,0,0)$ & \red & & \lime & & & \lime & & \red & \\      
 & $(1,1,1){\to}(0,1,0)$ & & \lime & & & \lime & \red & & & \\
 & $(1,0,0){\to}(0,1,0)$ & \red & \lime & & & \lime & \red & \red & & \lime\\
 & $(1,0,0){\to}(1,1,1)$ & & \red & \lime & &\red & & & \red & \\
\addlinespace[2ex]

1-Function Hazards
& $(0,1,1){\to}(1,0,1)$ & & \lime & & \red & \lime & & \red & & \lime\\
& $(0,0,0){\to}(0,1,1)$ & \lime & \red & & \lime & \red & & \lime & & \\
& $(0,0,0){\to}(1,0,1)$ & & \lime & & & \lime & & & \lime & \red\\
& $(1,0,1){\to}(0,1,1)$ & & & & & \red& \lime & \lime & \red &  \\      
& $(0,1,1){\to}(0,0,0)$ & & \red & & \lime & \red  & & \lime & & \red\\
& $(1,0,1){\to}(0,0,0)$ & & \red & & & \red& \lime & \lime & \red & \\
\addlinespace[2ex]

Wrong Steady State
& $(0,0,0)$ & \lime & \red & & \lime & \red & & \lime & & \red\\
& $(0,0,1)$ & & \red & \lime & \lime & & \red & & \red & \lime\\
& $(0,1,0)$ & & \red & \lime & & & \lime & & \red &\lime \\
& $(0,1,1)$ & \lime & \red & & \lime & \red & & \lime & \red & \\     
& $(1,0,0)$ & & & \lime & & & \lime & \lime & & \\
& $(1,0,1)$ & & \red & & & \red & & \red & & \lime\\
& $(1,1,0)$ & & \red & \lime & \red & & & & \red & \\
& $(1,1,1)$ & & \red & \lime & & \red & \lime & \lime & \red & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\footnotesize
This table compares each models' predictions for best and worst performance for each transition. A red color means that the circuit performed worse than the median, and green color means that the circuit performed better than the median, for that input molecule concentration or transition. \par
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico! This is really great